# Project Server 2010 - Resource Plan question

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know which database/table/view/fields holds the planned hours entered into a project's Resource Plan in Project Server 2010?

I came across some info on the internet where it's suggested to check it from Assignment Timephased Cube which contains "Time" dimension which in turn should give methe desired output by months, but I can't find this table in the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know which database/table/view/fields holds the planned hours entered into a project's Resource Plan in Project Server 2010?

No, but you can use SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to capture the queries that run when you save the information in the application. This should give you all the information you need.

One caution -- make sure every "hook" into a 3rd-party application is well-documented so it can be tested if you plan to do version upgrades in the future.